# Prometheus offset in seconds since midnight

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a counter metric of api calls. I would like to check how many calls were made TODAY (i.e since midnight). my initial though was to use the delta function which seems to fit, but I cannot figure out how do I calculate the offset from time() to midnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time() % 86400` will give the number of seconds since midnight UTC.

Comment: Thanks @brian-brazil, exactly what I was looking for. is there a way to use that value for a duration vector? (i.e delta(metric[(time() % 86400)s]))

Comment: No, you'd have to do that before the query gets to Prometheus.

Comment: @UriHellerman, did that help? :-) I am facing exactly the same problem. Querying from grafana and value needs to be calculated for every request (update)...

Answer (score 1):

When you are using grafana, you can tryout something like this: `delta(your_counter[${__range_s}s])`. There are several special variables in grafana: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get this data from midnight to the current appointment time?

```
sum(increase(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{alias="srvsquidproxy",device="ens160",instance="192.168.0.64:9100",job="Linux"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers or repeating the answered question. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.